# How to Reverse Hebrew String in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to reverse Hebrew string in Python:

```
line = 'אבגד'
reversed = line[::-1]
print reversed
```

but I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Care to explain what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I'm also trying to save the string into a file using:

```
w1 = open('~/fileName', 'w')
w1.write(reverseLine)
```

but now I get:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-3: character    maps to <undefined>
```

Any ideas how to fix that, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `u` in front of the hebrew string works for me:

```
In [1]: line = u'אבגד'

In [2]: reversed = line[::-1]

In [2]: print reversed
דגבא
```

---

To your second question, you can use:

```
import codecs

w1 = codecs.open("~/fileName", "r", "utf-8")
w1.write(reversed)
```

To write unicode string to file `fileName`.

Alternatively, without using `codecs`, you will need to encode `reversed` string with `utf-8` when writing to file:

```
with open('~/fileName', 'w') as f:
    f.write(reversed.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 9):

you need more than reverse a string to flip hebrew backwords, due to the opposite order of numbers etc.

The algorithms is much more complicated;

All the answers in this page (to this date) will most likely screw your numbers and non-hebrew texts.

For most cases you should use

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
print get_display(text)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching all over the internet for a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a unicode string constant:

```
line = u'אבגד'
reversed = line[::-1]
print reversed
```

Answer (score 1):

String defaults to being treated as ascii. Use u'' for unicode

```
line = u'אבגד'
reversed = line[::-1]
print reversed
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using unicode objects

```
line = unicode('אבגד', 'utf-8')
reversed = line[::-1]
print reversed
```

Comment: Hebrew character order is very complicated. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found how to write to file:

```
w1 = codecs.open('~/fileName', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
w1.write(reverseLine)
```